# How to disable TalkBack notifications

Tags: android, service, accessibility, screen-readers, talkback

I'm developing an aplication for the visual impaired.

As I'm using TTS, i want to disable all TalkBack notifications.

I've read a lot of post, but nothing seems to work. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks all!!

Comment: The user controls whether TalkBack is used via the Settings application.

Comment: Sorry, but i don´t understand you.